# How do I pass a variable as a parameter?

Tags: vb.net, variables, subroutine

I am a newbie in Visual Basic and I got stuck while trying to program a Tic Tac Toe game. I was trying to pass a variable as a parameter for a subroutine but I have no idea how. Here is my code.

```
    Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
        ButtonDisable(btn1)

    End Sub
    Public Sub ButtonDisable(ByVal ButtonSelected As Object)
        ButtonSelected.enable = False

    End Sub
```

In the code, I am trying to disable btn1 by running the variable as a parameter in a subroutine. Every time I debug the program, Visual basic tells me "Public member 'enable' on type 'Button' not found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your parameter is of the type `Object`, so inside the subroutine you can only use the members that are known to exist for `Object` instances. Change the type to `Button`, or the base class `Control`, to access the members that are specific to buttons, or controls.

```
Public Sub ButtonDisable(ByVal ButtonSelected As Button)
  ButtonSelected.Enabled = False
End Sub
```